# Can't access phone util on Galaxy S3 (I535)

Tags: usb, android, mobile-phone

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 that I can't get to connect to my computer.  I've tried multiple USB cables (including the default one from the charger) on multiple computers.

My next step is trying to access the PhoneUtil menu to make sure the USB mode is set correctly, but apparently the `*#7284#` doesn't exist on this phone.

I was wondering if anybody had any advice or alternatives to try.

**EDIT**

I was able to get to the menu by enabling hidden menus (code `*#22745927`) and then using (`*#7284#`).  I changed the USB Mode to MTP + ADB and it started loading the drivers and then said "the device has been unplugged" and hasn't worked anymore.  Still just looking for suggestions.

Comment: Not to say this needs to be migrated (it is on topic for Super User), but you might get better answers on [android.se].  Please don't cross-post, though; if you want the question there, you can use a moderator flag to request migration.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I have the same problem, can't get `*#7284#` to work.

Comment: @FredericoSchardong The edit code worked for me to get into phone utils, but I wasn't able to solve the original problem that way.  See if that secondary code works for you.

Comment: Did you solved your problem?! And *#22745927# does not work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Go into settings, Developer Options and see if turning on USB Debugging helps.  Another option is just install PDANET.  It has drivers included for about everything.
- Joe

Comment: USB Debugging didn't fix anything, I'll try PDANet if nothing else.